# Android time picker shows two clocks?

Tags: android, timepicker

I have implemented the Android time picker according to the android dev doc, and everything works fine, but I am having a strange bug with it. I searched for it a lot and didn't find anything so, I am asking here.

Here is my time picker:
[image: timepicker picture - to see the bug]

Here is the code for it:

```
 class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                    DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // Do something with the time chosen by the user
            if (hourOfDay < 10) {
                startTime.setText("0" + Integer.toString(hourOfDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
            } else if (minute < 10) {
                startTime.setText(Integer.toString(hourOfDay) + ":0" + Integer.toString(minute));
            } else if (hourOfDay < 10 && minute < 10) {
                startTime.setText("0" + Integer.toString(hourOfDay) + ":0" + Integer.toString(minute));
            } else if (minute == 0) {
                startTime.setText(Integer.toString(hourOfDay) + ":00");
            } else
                startTime.setText(Integer.toString(hourOfDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
        }
    }
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Post the relevant code here. Pictures of code are USELESS.

Comment: can you try something like `dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Comment: @AkshayShinde i am getting this when i call : dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: What you can do is, create a style with no title bar and apply it to your TimePickerDialog.

Comment: what is `startTime` in your code? Is that a `TextView` you added somewhere?

Comment: yes, it has nothing to do with the time picker dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced with the same issue on Samsung devices (Galaxy S5 and S6 in my case). I found that on this devices title is added by system and to hide that title all you need to do is to set it to null by your own.
[image: Hierarchy view of broken TimePickerDialog in my case]

```
TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, false);
dialog.setTitle(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TimePickerDialog (Context context, 
            int themeResId, 
            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener, 
            int hourOfDay, 
            int minute, 
            boolean is24HourView)
```

**is24HourView** : Whether this is a 24 hour view, or AM/PM.

try to set this parameter to **false**, I think you will get what you want.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html

Comment: He wanted to remove the extra time from dialog title.